# How to make head and body different colors

Tags: css, html

I want to make the head and body different things, independent from each other. Because of this, I want different background colors, but I've not been able to achieve that.

If anyone knows how I can make the styling for the head and body show up and make the sections look different, please let me know. I've included the code I used on the site below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <p>Hi there!</p>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
            head {
                background-color: lightgreen;
            }
        </style>
        <p>Hi there!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Image of the output:

[the page output](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=791329)

Comment: the <head> section is not visible on the html page and thus styling it will not work. <header> on the other case will work

Comment: Your HTML structure and use of tags is incorrect. You may want to consider starting with [**a basic tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `head` tag is used to describe metadata and important information about your document. What shows up there is not visible.

Your `p` tag should be under the `body` tag, not the head tag.

What you are thinking of is probably the `header` section of your webpage, which is included under your body tag.

Also, your css declarations should take place in their own separate file.
Here is what your code should look like

```
<html>

  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <p>Hi there!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Styles.css

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

header {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```